# .NET Mass Downloader with VS.NET 2005?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

After downloading all .NET framework symbols and sources using [NetMassDownloader](http://www.codeplex.com/NetMassDownloader), is it possible to setup the VS.NET 2005 for debugging into .NET 2.0 source files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can [download the symbols](https://web.archive.org/web/20160707213703/http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2007/05/23/Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2005-with-a-Symbol-Server.aspx), though they're not available for browsing.